Smart way to diagonalize a particular "big" matrix
Let $A$ be the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
I already know that since all of its rows sum up to the same number ---in this case 9--- then $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $9$.
Also since its rank is $2$ then $4$ of its eigenvalues are $0$. The kernel will be the subspace associated to this eigenvalue.

The question:
There's one eigenvalue missing. Is there a way of finding it without calculating the characteristic polynomial?

Sum of all eigenvalues = trace(A)

One way is to express the big matrix via the Kronecker product. We have
$$A=U\otimes V=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
The first factor, being the outer product of $(1,1,1)$ with itself, has the following eigenpairs:

$\lambda_1 =0$, $u_1=(2,-1,-1)^\top$
$\lambda_2 =0$, $u_2=(0,1,-1)^\top$
$\lambda_3 =3$, $u_3=(1,1,1)^\top$

(The first two eigenvectors are not unique but I've chosen them to be orthogonal.) The second factor can be diagonalized by inspection, with the following eigenpairs:

$\mu_1 =3,$ $v_1=(1,1)^\top$
$\mu_2=1,$ $v_2=(1,-1)^\top$

The mixed-product property of the Kronecker product then yields
$$A (u_j\otimes v_k)=(U\otimes V)(u_j\otimes v_k)=(Uu_j)\otimes (Vv_j)=\lambda_j \mu_k (u_j\otimes v_k)$$
That is, the eigenvectors of $A$ are Kronecker products of the eigenvectors of its Kronecker-product factors. Correspondingly, the six eigenvalues of $A$ are the six possible products of the three eigenvalues of $U$ and the two eigenvalues of $V$. Writing these out explicitly:

$\lambda_1 \mu_1 = 0$, $u_1\otimes v_1=(2,2,-1,-1,-1,-1)^\top$
$\lambda_2 \mu_1 = 0$, $u_2\otimes v_1=(0,0,1,1,-1,-1)^\top$
$\lambda_3 \mu_1 = 9$, $u_3\otimes v_1=(1,1,1,1,1,1)^\top$
$\lambda_1 \mu_2 = 0$, $u_1\otimes v_2=(2,2,-1,-1,-1,-1)^\top$
$\lambda_2 \mu_2 = 0$, $u_2\otimes v_2=(0,0,1,-1,-1,1)^\top$
$\lambda_3 \mu_2 = 3$, $u_3\otimes v_2=(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)^\top$


Obviously, this is overkill if all you need are the eigenvalues. The advantage of the Kronecker-product form is that it exposes the structure of the eigenvectors.

Also, another overkill way to do this is to note that this is a circulant matrix. Hence it can be diagonalized using Fourier modes. (Indeed, $u_3\otimes v_1$ and $u_3\otimes v_2$ are already examples of Fourier modes.)

Nice observations!
